# Apache Drill - DrillStartupException with CustomAuthenticaor

Tags: apache-drill

I tried creating a custom authenticator with Drill 1.5.0 by creating jar based on below source code and drill configuration. I placed the jar in `$DRILLHOME/jars/`

`drill-override.conf` File :

```
drill.exec: {   
  cluster-id: "drillbits1",  
  zk.connect: "host1:2181,host2:2181,host3:2181"   
 security.user.auth: {   
            enabled: true,  
            packages += “myorg.drill.security",  
            impl: “sso"  
       }   
}
```

`DrillMyUserAuthenticator` Class:

```
package myorg.drill.security;
import myorg.drill.security.SSOFilter;

import myorg.drill.security.SecurityServiceException;    
import org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig;    
import org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException;  
import org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security.UserAuthenticationException;    
import org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security.UserAuthenticator;   
import org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security.UserAuthenticatorTemplate;
       
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.net.InetAddress;   
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
  
@UserAuthenticatorTemplate(type = “sso") 
public class DrillMyUserAuthenticator implements UserAuthenticator {

private  String ipAddress;


    public void setup(DrillConfig drillConfig) throws DrillbitStartupException {

        try {
            ipAddress= InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new DrillbitStartupException(e);  
        }   
    }
    
    public void authenticate(String userName, String password) throws UserAuthenticationException {

        try { 
            SSOFilter.setSourceAddress(ipAddress); 
            SSOFilter.authenticate(userName, password);

        } catch (SecurityServiceException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            throw new UserAuthenticationException(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
    }  
}
```

And I am getting below exception:

> exception in thread "main" org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Failure while initializing values in Drillbit.
>
> at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:277)
>
> at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:261)
>
> at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.main(Drillbit.java:257)
>
> Caused by: org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Failed to find the implementation of 'org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security.UserAuthenticator' for type ’sso'
>
> at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.security.UserAuthenticatorFactory.createAuthenticator(UserAuthenticatorFactory.java:103)
>
> at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.UserServer.(UserServer.java:80)
>
> at org.apache.drill.exec.service.ServiceEngine.(ServiceEngine.java:79)
>
> at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.(Drillbit.java:89)
>
> at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.start(Drillbit.java:275)

Please let me know if I am missing something with the config or code.

I followed [Drill's documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-user-authentication/) to create this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out be a documentation issue on Drill Side. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4461

Above Jira has the solution to the problem.New jar for the custom authenticator should be created with drill-module.conf in order for the classpath scanner to pick it up

```
drill: {
  classpath.scanning: {
    packages: [
    "myorg.drill.security"
    ]
  }
}
```